# docker stucks when executing time.sleep(1) in a python loop

Tags: python, loops, docker, docker-compose, sleep

With the use of `docker-compose` and `python:2.7`, it runs correctly when executing only `while 1` loop and `time.sleep(1)` separately.

But it stucks when executing them together.

Here is the docker version and the file content on my `mac`

```
tmp docker -v
Docker version 1.12.5, build 7392c3b
tmp cat docker-compose.yml
version: '2'
services:
    test:
        image: python:2.7
        command: [python, -c, "print 0\nwhile 1:\n\tprint 1\n\tbreak"]
tmp docker-compose up
Creating network "tmp_default" with the default driver
Creating tmp_test_1
Attaching to tmp_test_1
test_1  | 0
test_1  | 1
tmp_test_1 exited with code 0
tmp cat docker-compose.yml
version: '2'
services:
    test:
        image: python:2.7
        command: [python, -c, "print 0\nimport time\nprint time.sleep(1)"]
tmp docker-compose up
Recreating tmp_test_1
Attaching to tmp_test_1
test_1  | 0
test_1  | None
tmp_test_1 exited with code 0
tmp cat docker-compose.yml
version: '2'
services:
    test:
        image: python:2.7
        command: [python, -c, "print 0\nimport time\nwhile 1:\n\tprint time.sleep(1)"]
tmp docker-compose up
Recreating tmp_test_1
Attaching to tmp_test_1
```

and here it stucks.

Hope to know the reason and the method to fix it, thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add `-u` flag to python in order to have unbuffered stdout:

```
command: [python, -uc, "print 0\nimport time\nwhile 1:\n\tprint time.sleep(1)"]
```

Comment: It works. And in man page of python there are details about internal buffering. Thanks.